# How to overwrite `command` field in airflow's `docker-compose.yml`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm currently using a [docker-compose.yml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) to run a airflow cluster.
And I'm doing a little customization on this to configure some environment in airflow cluster.

Belows are my working directory(called `my_application`) structure:

```
 ➜ tree -L 2
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── configs
│     ├── configure_all.sh
│     ├── create_connections.sh
│     ├── requirements
│     └── variables.json
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0-python3.8
USER root

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential gcc git wget unzip \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow/my_application"

USER airflow
```

And `docker-compose.yml`(please pay attention to `volumes` and `command` part in `x-airflow-common`):

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'

  volumes:
    - .:/opt/airflow/my_application
  command: sh /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh   

services:
  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - selenium
  ...
```

When I run `docker-compose up` command, it doesn't work (looks like `sh /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh` is overwritten by each service's command)

I've also replaced with each `command` with like `sh /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh && scheduler`, but it doesn't work either:

```
Creating my_application_airflow-scheduler_1 ... done
Attaching to my_application_airflow-scheduler_1
airflow-scheduler_1  | BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
airflow-scheduler_1  | DB_HOST=postgres
airflow-scheduler_1  | DB_PORT=5432
airflow-scheduler_1  |
airflow-scheduler_1  |
airflow-scheduler_1  | airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: invalid choice: 'sh' (choose from 'celery', 'cheat-sheet', 'config', 'connections', 'dags', 'db', 'info', 'jobs', 'kerberos', 'kubernetes', 'plugins', 'pools', 'providers', 'roles', 'rotate-fernet-key', 'scheduler', 'sync-perm', 'tasks', 'users', 'variables', 'version', 'webserver'), see help above.
airflow-scheduler_1  | usage: airflow [-h] GROUP_OR_COMMAND ...
airflow-scheduler_1  |
airflow-scheduler_1  | positional arguments:
airflow-scheduler_1  |   GROUP_OR_COMMAND
airflow-scheduler_1  |
airflow-scheduler_1  |     Groups:
airflow-scheduler_1  |       celery         Celery components
airflow-scheduler_1  |       config         View configuration
airflow-scheduler_1  |       connections    Manage connections
airflow-scheduler_1  |       dags           Manage DAGs
airflow-scheduler_1  |       db             Database operations
airflow-scheduler_1  |       jobs           Manage jobs
airflow-scheduler_1  |       kubernetes     Tools to help run the KubernetesExecutor
airflow-scheduler_1  |       pools          Manage pools
airflow-scheduler_1  |       providers      Display providers
airflow-scheduler_1  |       roles          Manage roles
airflow-scheduler_1  |       tasks          Manage tasks
airflow-scheduler_1  |       users          Manage users
airflow-scheduler_1  |       variables      Manage variables
airflow-scheduler_1  |
airflow-scheduler_1  |     Commands:
airflow-scheduler_1  |       cheat-sheet    Display cheat sheet
airflow-scheduler_1  |       info           Show information about current Airflow and environment
airflow-scheduler_1  |       kerberos       Start a kerberos ticket renewer
airflow-scheduler_1  |       plugins        Dump information about loaded plugins
airflow-scheduler_1  |       rotate-fernet-key
airflow-scheduler_1  |                      Rotate encrypted connection credentials and variables
airflow-scheduler_1  |       scheduler      Start a scheduler instance
airflow-scheduler_1  |       sync-perm      Update permissions for existing roles and optionally DAGs
airflow-scheduler_1  |       version        Show the version
airflow-scheduler_1  |       webserver      Start a Airflow webserver instance
airflow-scheduler_1  |
airflow-scheduler_1  | optional arguments:
airflow-scheduler_1  |   -h, --help         show this help message and exit
```

It looks like the `command` always run like `airflow [command]` as a default so it can't be run cuz `airflow` doesn't know about the `sh`.
(And that's why each command in other serivce is described as an one word(`scheduler`, `celery worker`))

Is there any way to overwrite this `command` with like `sh /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh && airflow scheduler`?

What I've tried in other ways:

1. Run `sh /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh` in the Dockerfile [failed]

- Why failed?

  - Because `volumes` mount happend after building image.
  - So, It can't access `/opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh` in building time
  - I've also tried using `CMD` instead of `RUN`, but it doesn't work neither.

2. COPY `configs` in the Dockerfile and RUN `sh /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh` [failed]

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0-python3.8
USER root

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential gcc git wget unzip \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow/my_application"

USER airflow

COPY ./configs /configs
RUN sh /configs/configure_all.sh
```

- Why failed?

  - In `configure_all.sh`, it try to create connections(in Airflow), e.g. `airflow connections add "slack_token" --conn-type="token" --conn-password=${MY_TOKEN}`, so it needs a database to create a connection in.
    But in the building time, database is not yet available(postgres runs in `docker-compose` time) so it runs but no connection is created :(

Comment: Airflow runs this script on startup. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/in_container/prod/entrypoint_prod.sh As you can see, the final line runs `airflow` + any parameters you pass it. You can override the entrypoint to run your `sh` command, but then the rest of the Airflow startup script won't get run. Your best bet is probably to modify the script and put your version in `/entrypoint` in your image.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to override the entrypoint rather than the command. You just have to run airflow's startup script yourself then

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'

  volumes:
    - .:/opt/airflow/my_application
  
  entrypoint: /opt/airflow/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh && /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /entrypoint
```